# MongoDB 3.0.7 install on 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, 32-bit

So I have been having numerous problems trying to simply install mongodb 3.0.7. Every article/documentation I have read and tried to follow, pretty much defaulted me to version 2.4.9.  I think I heard something about incompatibility about mongodb with 32-bit, but I am not too sure.

I have tried using the below links to install mongodb

- http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-install-up-mongodb-and-php-on-ubuntu/
- https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I even tried using a `wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.7.tgz` , then  `tar zxvf mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.7.tgz` on the package and I was able to install it, unpackage it, but after that nothing worked.

I am officially stuck and would like some guidance. I thought this would be a simple task, but it turned out to be daunting.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: After you `untarred`, what error message did you receive ? It should work.

Comment: have you started mongodb server using `./mongod`? what error is shown ?

Comment: There are no 32 bits packages for MongoDB 3.

Check [this link](http://serverfault.com/questions/679317/why-cant-i-install-mongodb-3-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-32bit).

Comment: Mongodb is broken as designed and doubly so on half the bits. On 32-bit computers you can expect database corruption when your DB size hits 2GiB.

Answer (score 0):

Please try beow commonds on **ubuntu 14.04 but with 64 bit O.S**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

If anyone is still looking for answer